# Location Manager's addProximityAlert() dosent get fired for Api level greater than 16

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have been into this problem for days without any improvements and hopes of this code working. The `addProximityAlert()` of the `locationmanager` doesn't get fired or triggered in `API` level greater than 16. It works perfectly in `API level 16` but not on **API 17 and higher**.

Has the `method` been `deprecated` in  the `higher api` or am i missing something there?

The `broadcastreciever` is totally fine and works if called manually.

The `pendingintent` is also fine and works when started manually.

The only problem that seems to be here is the `addProximityAlert()` itself.

There are lots of other questions relating this topic, but none seems to be answering this issue. Would be really glad if some one helped me figure this out.

My code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    double lat = 37.422000;
    double lon = -122.084095;
    float radius = 5.0f * 1609.0f;


    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT);
    pIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    locMgr = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,new MyLocationListener());

    locMgr.addProximityAlert(lat, lon, radius, 2000l, pIntent1);

    proxReceiver = new ProximityReceiver();

    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT);
    registerReceiver(proxReceiver, iFilter);

}

class ProximityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("==>","broadcast recieved");
    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    if (entering) {
        Log.d("==>", "entering");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("==>", "exiting");
    }
  }
}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Location pointLocation = getLocation();
        float distance = location.distanceTo(pointLocation);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Distance from Point:" + distance, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Before API version 17, this method could be used with
>   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. From API version 17
>   and onwards, this method requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

Comment: thanks for your interest, but i have set the permissions for both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and still doesnt work. :(

Comment: Please remove the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission and try again. Maybe this is that causes the issue

Comment: tried with only ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ... no success! Any other ideas you might have regarding to this issue?

Comment: Do you test this on a real device or on an emulator?

Comment: yes in both ... if the api level for the emulator is 16 or below that it works perfectly, but on the emulator with api level 17 and 21 it fails. since my real device is also on api level 21, there is no success there too.